# Error updating SOLineSplit throws error: "'Related Document' may not be empty" when saving

Tags: acumatica

I have made a UI (gridform) that let's the user view SOLineSplit, SOLine, SOOrder (all of these are acumatica DACs)- **the objective is to be able to update/modify the allocation quantity (quantity) in SOLineSplit easily**.

```
Namespace AllocationUpdate
{
    public class AllocationUpdateEntry : PXGraph<AllocationUpdateEntry>
    {
        public PXSave<SOLineSplit> Save;
        public PXCancel<SOLineSplit> Cance;
        public PXSelectJoin<SOLineSplit, 
            RightJoin<SOLine, 
                On<SOLine.orderNbr, Equal<SOLineSplit.orderNbr>, 
                And<SOLine.inventoryID, Equal<SOLineSplit.inventoryID>,
                And<SOLine.subItemID, Equal<SOLineSplit.subItemID>>>>,
            RightJoin<SOOrder, 
                On<SOOrder.orderNbr, Equal<SOLine.orderNbr>>>>,
            Where<SOLineSplit.isAllocated, Equal<True>>> Document;
```

but it throws error about OrderDate can't be empty. so i added the ff code in the BLC:

```
public class SOLineCacheExtension : PXCacheExtension<SOLineSplit>
        {
            #region OrderDate
            public abstract class orderDate : IBqlField
            {
            }
            [PXDBDate]
            public DateTime? OrderDate { get; set; }
            #endregion
```

but now it throws the "'Related Document' may not be empty" Error.
i tried modifying it like i did in OrderDate, but to no avail.

**How can we solve this? Thank you.**

FYI. Related Document of SOLineSplit is this field:

```
#region refnoteID
 [PXRefNote]
 [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Related Document", Enabled = false)]
 public virtual Guid? RefNoteID { get; set; }
#endregion
```

Comment: You are missing the parent DAC for SOLineSplit. @Samvel Petrosov's response should help solve your issue. (these are views to be added to your page graph)

Comment: I already tried Samvel's suggestion, but the error is sitll the same. Take note that i use Gridview not formview

Comment: when does the error occur? during save/persist? Debug and see if current is set on the SOOrder/SOLine views...

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the following `PXSelect`- s to your `Graph` so that attributes on `SOLineSplit` can work with the Cache of `SOOrder` and `SOLine`.

```
public PXSelect<SOOrder,Where<SOOrder.orderNbr,Equal<Current<SOLineSplit.orderNbr>>,
     And<SOOrder.orderType,Equal<Current<SOLineSplit.orderType>>> CurrentOrder;

public PXSelect<SOLine,Where<SOLine.orderNbr,Equal<Current<SOLineSplit.orderNbr>>,
     And<SOLine.orderType,Equal<Current<SOLineSplit.orderType>>,
     And<SOLine.lineNbr,Equal<Current<SOLineSplit.lineNbr>>>> CurrentLine;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just Inserting another (with different Qty). I don't think it allows me to update it. But the behavior of the original uncustomized Acumatica seems to just perform Insert operation and thus, my answer.